# Jinja2 lowercase only bool values

Tags: jinja2

I have a dictionary of values, some of the values are integer, some are strings, some are boolean. In my jinja2 template I currently use this:

```
{% for key, value in account.properties.items() %}
    <property key="{{ key }}" value="{{ value|string }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is, that I want boolean values to be all lowercase, everything else should stay normal. Right now I get `False` and `True` instead of `false` and `true`.
I also tried with to_json, but then the string values have quotes and integer and bool doesn't, so for above example I have then ""string"" which is also something I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I now use to_json and replace to remove quotes. Still this could be a potential issue for strings with escaped quotes I guess, e.g. `"foo\"bar". But for now I'm not aware to have those.

```
value="{{ value | to_json | replace("\"", "") }}"
```